# Remove dot at the end of number

Tags: python

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
  1,           0.,           0.,           0.
  2,           0.,           0.,         600.
  3,           0.,           0.,        2600.
  4,           0.,           0.,          50.
```

I'd like to read it and create the following list:

```
['1', '0', '0', '0']
['2', '0', '0', '600']
['3', '0', '0', '2600']
['4', '0', '0', '50']
```

However I only manage to obtain:

```
['1', '0.', '0.', '0.']
['2', '0.', '0.', '600.']
['3', '0.', '0.', '2600.']
['4', '0.', '0.', '50.']
```

My code looks like:

```
for line in inputFile:
    fileData.append([x.strip() for x in line.split(',')])
```

EDIT:
How can I convert my list of strings into a list of integers? tried some variations using the line of code I wrote above but couldn't make it.

Comment: if you eventually have to convert them into integers you can do: `[int(float(i)) for i in line.split(',')]`

Comment: Just read my mind! awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('filename') as f:
    file_data = [[int(float(i)) for i in line.split(',')] for line in f]
```

Comment: This won't work reliably for very large numbers. For example, on my system, `int(float("10000000000000001."))` gives you `10000000000000000` instead of `10000000000000001` as one might expect.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman -- I agree, in that case you should resort to string methods. The positive side is that using `float()` is about twice as fast as any of the other solutions proposed...

Answer (score 8):

Pass `"." + string.whitespace` to `strip` so that it strips both the spaces and the periods:

```
from string import whitespace
for line in inputFile:
    fileData.append([int(x.strip("." + whitespace)) for x in line.split(',')])
```

Comment: This will leave elements like `'0.\n'` at the end of each list.

Answer (score 4):

```
for line in inputFile:
    fileData.append([int(x.strip().rstrip('.')) for x in line.split(',')])
```

Instead of `x.strip().rstrip('.')`, you could use `x.strip(' \t\r\n.')`, but I think it is cleaner to let `x.strip()` handle all of the whitespace.